# How do you interpret the parameters obtained from lasso logistic regression when the response is binary?

Tags: logistic, lasso, regularization, glmnet

Are we still able to interpret the parameters in the same manner as we would in ordinary logistic regression? I'm asking this because I'm toying with the german credit data  https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Statlog+(German+Credit+Data) and doing a lasso logistic regression model to perform feature selection. I'm using the good_bad credit variable as the response and I'm using this model with the intent of obtaining probabilities for defaulting on a loan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: yes, you can interpret them in the exact same way as for the un-regularized Lasso.

Longer answer - a nice interpretation of Lasso logistic regression is a generalized linear model where the parameters have a Laplacian prior - so the relationship between $E[y]$ and $\vec{x}$ is still the same as in the simple logistic regression model.